# How to store Primeng Editor's Text to database and retrieving back?

Tags: angular

```
<p-editor [(ngModel)]="test" [style]="{'height':'320px'}" >
    <p-header>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-bold" title="Bold" ></button>
            <button class="ql-italic" title="Italic"></button>
            <button class="ql-underline" title="Underline"></button>
            <button class="ql-clean" title="Clean"></button>
            <button class="ql-align" value="center" title="Center"></button>
           <button class="ql-align" value="right" title="Right"></button>
           <button class="ql-list" value="ordered" title="Ordered List"></button>
            <button class="ql-list" value="bullet" title="Bulleted List"></button>
        </span>
    </p-header>
</p-editor>
```

This is my Primeng editor code.
I want to store text from editor to database and retrive back.
Kindly help?

Comment: This is same as what you have done for normal input text.

Comment: But my data is in  <p>Hiie</p><p><br></p> form.

Comment: Do you have any error ?